# Cant get Python to add within my code

Tags: python, addition

I am creating a code that will put messages into numbers based off of their position in my alp string and adding the value of the given key number.
For example, if I want to code "HI" with key code of 2, it would be 9 10. Because H's position is 7, and I's position is 8, and we added 2 to each number position.
Every time I run this, I get Error "Int not iterable":

```
def main():

    message=input("Enter your message to code: ")
    key=int(input("What is the key value?"))
    alp="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 .,?!"
    for letters in message:
        inString=int(alp.index(letters))
        print(inString)

    for numStr in inString:
        code=numStr+key
        print(code)
```

however, I tried to change it to this:

```
def main():

    message=input("Enter your message to code: ")
    key=int(input("What is the key value?"))
    alp="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 .,?!"
    for letters in message:
        inString=int(alp.index(letters))
        print(inString)

    for numStr in str(inString):
        code=(int(numStr)+key)
        print(code)



main()
```

this time, I got

```
Enter your message to code: HI
What is the key value?2



7
8
10
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running Python2 or 3?

Comment: @busfault that's entirely valid syntax in Python2, and does exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: @busfault: It doesn't, because that syntax works on Python 2 and people do it. More telling is the lack of a NameError from `input` when the user types `HI`.

Comment: It prints `7` and `8` in the first loop because those are the positions of `H` and `I` within `alp` (remember, Python indexing begins at zero, not one).  It then prints `10` in the second loop because `inString` is left with a value of 8 from the first loop, to which you add the value of `key` (which is 2).

Comment: @WayneWerner Doh. My apologies, I have rarely if **ever** seen `print(...)` in Python 2.x code.

Comment: @busfault and now you know :) There's also `from __future__ import print_function` that exports that back to Python2 ;)

Comment: FWIW (A little history) not all 2.x Python supports that. Only 2.6+ (that'll learn me to not keep up with changes to the language!)

Comment: I am using Python 3. Do I need 2 loops? one that pulls index of the position and the second loop will add 2 to each position? I tried but kept getting int not iterable??

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a list to store the numbers into and then you can iterate over that list.

```
inString = []
for letters in message:
    inString.append(int(alp.index(letters)))
    #print(inString)

for numStr in inString:
    code=(int(numStr)+key)
    print(code)
```

The 7 and 8 outputs you got were the right indexes. However, your `inString` was being overwritten on every loop. So in the end `inString` was just equal to 8 and the last for loop ran only once with the value 8.

Comment: I tried to add a loop within... How do I need to adjust this so that, it takes the position of each letter, and adds <key> to it?  I did this and it still says int not iterable?

Comment: Because your `inString` is an integer and you can't iterate over integers. The code that I posted does exactly what you asked for in the question, so I'm not really sure why you would want to add more loops. You should probably also read about the logic behind for loops in general: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm